# Docker - store output on local filesystem

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

I've got a docker-container that's running a program which outputs something. I want that something to be stored on my local file system, not in a volume. Bind mounts are what I need.

I have a single folder called `oniongen` and this is where I want the output.

My compose file looks like this:

```
version: '3'
services:
  oniongen:
     image: nwtgck/mkp224o
     volumes:
     - ./oniongen:/gen
     command: >
      sh -c "mkp224o abcd -d gen"
```

However, the outputs never reach my local file system.

[image]

I've tried

```
volumes:
  oniongen:
    driver: local
```

and this incarnation just in case

```
volumes:
  oniongen:
```

and also specifying `bind` under volume type

```
services:
  oniongen:
    image: nwtgck/mkp224o
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./oniongen
        target: /gen
volumes:
  oniongen:
```

I've tried other suggestions too and read the docs, but can't seem to get the output stored locally.

If I `sh` into the container I can see the `gen` folder and the files in it.

How do I get these files to be stored on my local system?

Answer (score 1):

You're really over-complicating it, just mount a local folder as your volume:

```yaml
services:
  oniongen:
    image: nwtgck/mkp224o
    volumes:
      - ./oniongen:/gen
```

No need for the `volumes` top level declaration either.

This will result in everything the container puts in its `/gen` folder appearing in the host's `./oniongen` folder and vice-versa.

Comment: That's exactly what I did in the first instance (as I said). I only tried top level declaration to see if that helped (mostly because I thought maybe I needed the `local` driver). I'll add a screenshot.

Comment: @ron_g looking at your screenshot, you're providing `gen` as an argument to your script not `/gen`, that might be something to do with it. Try changing your command to `touch /gen/test` and see if the file shows up

Comment: Thanks. The issue was within the image itself. In the last line (https://github.com/nwtgck/docker-mkp224o/blob/master/Dockerfile) it had `WORKDIR /root`. I copied the Dockerfile and added a line just before (`COPY ./gen /root/data`, with the corresponding `./gen:/root/data` as my volume in the compose file) and it worked.